# Htaccess Redirect command case insensitive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my `.htaccess` I have a lot of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRules` but below that I have some simple `Redirect` commands:

`Redirect /fancypageurl /some/page/url`

This works fine, however is there a way to make it case insensitive? I know there is a case insensitive flag for  `RewriteRule`.  Every time I google `Redirect` command syntax i get results for the rewrite rule.

I just need to redirect people if they go to `/FancyPageURL` or `/fancyPAGEurl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Redirect` doesn't support any flags and it doesn't support regex either.

You can use `RedirectMatch` with modifier (?i)`:

```
RedirectMatch (?i)^/fancypageurl/?$ /some/page/url
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe you're missing a $ `(?i)^/fancypageurl$`